# how to resolve unexpected null value

Tags: flutter, dart

I added a float button in my application while clicking on it two text-field appear , without adding *formKey*  the button works but when i use it to controle if the field text are empty or not by if statement *if (formKey.currentState!.validate())* in the Debug Console i get this error

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Unexpected null value.
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

this the code of floating button

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (isBottomSheetShown) {
              if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                isBottomSheetShown = false;
                setState(() {
                  fabIcon = Icons.edit;
                });
              }
            } else {
              scaffoldKey.currentState!.showBottomSheet(
                (context) => Container(
                  color: Colors.grey[100],
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        TextField(
                          controller: titleController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.title),
                            hintText: 'write a title',
                            labelText: 'Title',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          controller: timeController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.watch_later_outlined),
                            hintText: 'write a time',
                            labelText: 'Time',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            showTimePicker(
                              context: context,
                              initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                            ).then((value) {
                              timeController.text =
                                  value!.format(context).toString();
                              print(value!.format(context));
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            isBottomSheetShown = true;
            setState(() {
              fabIcon = Icons.add;
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            fabIcon,
          )),
```

Answer (score 1):

The Unexpected null value is occurring because you're asserting that `formKey.currentState` is not null before you validate it, so if currentState equals null, it will throw that error.

I'd suggest first checking if `formKey.currentState != null` before calling the validate method.

Comment: I can just click one time on the floating button . Once i click one time , the text field does not appear if i repeat the clicking